# Validating a quiz in python such that the only valid inputs for retaking the quiz are 'y' or 'n'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, input, while-loop

I am using Python 3.1.3 and I am trying to write  a quiz to test my own knowledge of the element names and corresponding atomic numbers of the periodic table, using random number generators to choose between whether to ask the user for the atomic number or element name and which element to ask about.
I am currently trying to validate all user inputs. I have successfully validated the numerical and alphabetical inputs but am struggling to validate a 'yes' or 'no' option for re-taking the quiz, accepting the inputs: 'y' or 'n'.
I had previously tried to use several IF and ELIF statements to determine whether the user has given an input that is equal to the valid inputs but after searching stack overflow I changed my code to be like this:

```
##Functions
def validating_y_or_n_only(a,b,c):
    while b == 0:
        if not a:
            print("\n\tYou didnt enter anything.")
        elif a in ["y","n"]:
            b = 1
        else :
            print("\n\tYour input was invalid.")
        print("\tOnly 'y' and 'n' are considered valid.\n")
        print(c)
        a = str(input("\tEnter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no: "))
    return a

##Main Program
retake = "\n\tWould you like to re-take the quiz?"
print(retake)
replay_option = str(input("\tEnter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no: "))
replay_option = validating_y_or_n_only(replay_option,condition,retake)
```

However this creates an infinite loop and even the valid inputs of 'y' or 'n' or not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems overcomplicated. There are many variables which seem to be unnecessary or not used. It's also good practice to use meaningful names instead of `a`, `b`, `c`.

Here's one solution which uses `break` within a `while` loop to indicate when valid data has been input.

```
def validating_y_or_n_only():
    while True:
        answer = str(input("\tEnter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no: "))
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            break
        elif not answer:
            print('\n\tYou didnt enter anything.')
        else:
            print('\n\tYour input was invalid.')
            print('\tOnly "y" and "n" are considered valid.\n')
    return answer

replay_option = validating_y_or_n_only()
```

Comment: thanks for the code, however I don't know much about python and was wondering whether the first IF statement you gave uses a tuple or a list, or whether there is a difference in the outcome in this instance. Also, what does the 'True' condition do?

Comment: 2 separate questions here: (1) You can use ` tuple`, `set`, or `list`. In this context, `in` will work with any of `{'y', 'n'}, ['y', 'n'], ('y', 'n')`. (2) `while True` means continue in your loop until you reach `break`.